# How to receive the number of specific entries from XML-file?

Tags: xml, bash

XML-file contains departments and users from a company next to some other comments. The number of users vary, also the last comment after the user:

```
 <department="marketing" id="983343" >
   <options="yes" />
   <prefix="m" />
   <country="de" />
   <user="MaierM" />
        .
        .
        .
   <user="SchulzP" />
   <success="yes" />
 </department>
 <department="sales" id="353934" >
   <options="yes" />
   <prefix="s" />
   <country="at" />
   <user="MullerS" />
        .
        .
        .
   <user="NowakA" />
   <directory="direct" />
 </department>
```

My question is: If I just would like to get the number of the users of a department based on id (here: 983343) dumped in a variable - what would be the bash-command (Python cannot be used)? Note too that the id might exist at another point as well inside the XML file with a different meaning that time.

Comment: Your `xml` is not well-formed. You should fix it first.

Comment: You are likely right, even I do not see in the moment, where it is mal-formed. I just simplified an existing one as I was hoping to achieve a better understanding that way. However I am confident that the idea of the XML-file is obvious, therefore I am looking forward to receive solution suggestions here...

Comment: We already discussed this issue in one of your previous questions, so you already know what I'm talking about. I would try to help you using any `xml` parser but I can't because they tell me that your input is wrong. And using any text processing tool from the shell is inconsistent based in the `xml` specification. I'm sure you will receive solution suggestions but I'm not sure they will be a good approach. You will avoid many headaches using well-formed `xml` data, and I guess at the end you will realise it the wrong way.

Comment: XML may only have one root element. Your snippet has two. You're probably missing some element like `<departments/>` wrapping the others. EDIT: Your XML is completely messed up. That's no XML at all.

Comment: Until your XML is well-formed, this is not an XML question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var=`sed -n '/department=..* id="983343"/,/<\/department>/p' file | grep -c '<user="'`
```

First I tell `sed` to print lines between the start of your specific department and its closing tag.

The result is piped into `grep` which looks for lines with a `user` tag, but counts them instead of printing them (-c option).

The entire command is placed inside backticks, so you can capture the count into a variable using command substitution.

Comment: Great answer! Understood my point with the XML, provided a solution and explained in detail. Exactly that kind of help I was looking for :-D.

Comment: I can feel a slightest bit of bitterness against the XML zealots in your comment. But I must be wrong... :-)